# why current page link is not different in my code?

Tags: html, css

here is my style for navigation bar but its not working...
i am a new learner of CSS styling plz help me how to do that ...
here my active id is not working i dont know where is the mistake...

```
 #navibar 
 {
 list-style-type:none;
 font-family:"Verdana";
 letter-spacing:5px;
 width:180px;
 padding:5px;
 margin-left:20px;
 }
 #navibar li
 {
 padding:10px;
 }
 #navibar li a
 {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#333333;
 font-size:20px;
 padding:5px;
 transition:padding-left 1s;
 -moz-transition:padding-left 1s;
 -webkit-transition:padding-left 1s;
 -o-transition:padding-left 1s;
 }
 #navibar li a:hover
 { 
 color:#fff;
 background-image:url(ul.png);
 background-position:left;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 padding-left:20px;
 }

#active li a:link
{
color:#fff;
background-image:url(ul.png);
background-position:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-left:20px;
}
</style>
```

and this my html code

```
<ul id="navibar">
    <li><a id="active" href="">Stories</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

i have created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KByUF/)

Thanks in advavce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### edit:

depending on your css, this will do what you want

```
#navibar li a#active
```

### original post:

```
#active li a:link
```

your code above will apply the settings to a "link" inside of a "li" inside of an id "active"..

what you want is

```
li #active
```

or

```
ul li #active
```

or just

```
#active
```

or whatever ;-)

Comment: ul li #active is working only :)
Thank you very much....

Comment: ok fine, do you also understand now how this is working?